# clicking attribute on a page via Userscript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

i am trying to make a userscript in chrome tampermonkey that will auto click the "Gen.lib.rus.ec" link in pages like [this](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=7485D03F9ED332CB32E0A2250A26DBAD). classname is always dynamic but not the title name. i know how to make it work by classname but not title. kindly suggest something.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         libgen  clicker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @include      *://libgen.rs/*
// @match      *://libgen.rs/*
// @include      *://library.lol/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=libgen.rs
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
    
setTimeout(function() {
document.getattribute("Gen.lib.rus.ec")[0].click();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `a[title="Gen.lib.rus.ec"]` CSS selector with e.g. `document.querySelector` to get the proper element based on the title attribute.